# VBA Clear Clipboard after execution of each loop

Tags: excel, vba, copy

I have following code, that saves large amounts of data into clipboard every time the code runs I need to select No on the clipboard notification. I have tried CutCopyMode = False and would like to avoid surpressing notifications. Does anyone any input on how to modify the code below to clear clipboard after each loop?

```
    Dim filePath As String
    Dim SourceWb As Workbook
    Dim TargetWb As Workbook
    Dim Cell As Range
    Dim i As Integer
    Dim k As Integer
    Dim Lastrow As Long

    
    'SourceWb - Workbook were data is copied from
    'TargetWb - Workbook were data is copied to and links are stored
    
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    
    Set TargetWb = Application.Workbooks("APC Refi Tracker.xlsb")
    Lastrow = Range("F100").End(xlUp).Row - 6

        For k = 1 To Lastrow
        
            filePath = TargetWb.Sheets("Import").Range("F" & 6 + k).Value
            Set SourceWb = Workbooks.Open(filePath)
        
        On Error Resume Next
            Range("A1").CurrentRegion.Copy
            TargetWb.Sheets("Balance Sheet Drop").Range("D" & 2 + (k - 1) * 149).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
            SourceWb.Close
        Next

Application.ScreenUpdating = True

Worksheets("Import").Activate

    MsgBox "All done!"

End Sub
```

Comment: `.Copy` a single cell in the end and then set CutCopyMode = False.

Comment: Thanks @GSerg that stopped the notification